Якорная ссылка на мобильной (планшетной) версии срабатывает на второй раз Wordpress
Элемент с id на который ссылается якорная ссылка:
<div id="faq" data-anchor="#faq" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid bg-gray" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px"></div>

И сама якорная ссылка:
<a href="#!/faq" data-level="1"><i class="fa fa-commenting">
   </i><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Вопросы- 
   Ответы</span></span>
</a>

Сайт на Wordpress - может есть какая то особенность у CMS или что я делаю не так ?
Проблема возникает на этой странице
Саму ссылку пробовала ставить в разных вариантах:  https://bckln.webworkers.pro/#faq  и  /#faq  не помогло

Первое, что бросается в глаза, это не корректный href адрес. Должно быть так
<a href="#faq" data-level="1"><i class="fa fa-commenting"> если увазаный элемент с id="faq" действительно есть на данной странице.
